# How to set search phrase and execute it for Bootstrap DataTable on page load?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I've a html page with Bootstrap DataTable. I want to set search phrase and execute it for the DataTable on page load.

Description:-
I've two links in my home page which are hyper-linked to this 'DataTable page'. When i click 'link1' i want to load 'DataTable Page' with some search phrase and execute it and  when i click 'link2' i want to load the same with some other search phrase.

I can set LocalStorage for different search phrase but how to load the DataTable with those. I think i've clearly described my problem.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: do you want to execute the search or just set the search phrase, for execution by the user if they desire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#example').dataTable();
} );


$('#some_link_btn').click(function(){
   $('#example_filter').find('input[type=text]').val('your search phrase');
   $('#example_filter').find('input[type=text]').trigger('keyup');
});
```